# custom vertical line based on user input during run time

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

Currently i add v line as follow:

```
axvline(y= uservalue, linewidth=1, linestyle=':', color='orangered')
```

after drawing a plot, during the runtime,  is there way to get the uservalue and update the line position?  Basically i want to get the user input during the run time and update the plot accordingly.